# Translating `defadvice` to `advice-add` for modification of modes

Tags: advice, obsolete

With Emacs 30.1 `defadvice` has become obsolete, and one should use `advice-add` or `define-advice` instead. The Emacs-manual outlines how to transition from `defadvice` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-Old-Advice.html). I understand the principle of advice, but a lot of my packages are configured using `defadvice`-pieces I took up from here and there and are using snippets that aren't really functions. For instance here

```
(use-package abbrev
  :config
  (setq-default abbrev-mode nil)
  (defadvice expand-abbrev (after my-expand-abbrev activate)
   ;; if there was an expansion
   (if ad-return-value
       ;; start idle timer to ensure insertion of abbrev activator
       ;; character (e.g. space) is finished
       (run-with-idle-timer 0 nil
                            (lambda ()
                              ;; if there is the string "@@" in the
                              ;; expansion then move cursor there and
                              ;; delete the string
                              (let ((cursor "@@"))
                                (if (search-backward cursor last-abbrev-location t)
                                    (delete-char (length cursor))))))))
)
```

the `my-expand-abbrev activate`-piece isn't one, right? I tried to evaluate it but Emacs treats the expressions as undefined variables. So I'm confused. How do I translate something like this to `advice-add`?

Comment: FWIW: Obsolete doesn't mean it's not supported. At least it *shouldn't* mean loss of support. Things should continue to be supported until they're desupported. Does the code in question not still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Drew’s advice (pun intended); there is no urgent need to convert to `advice-add`. It’ll be years before `defadvice` goes away.

Still, might as well point out the obvious. Use `C-h f` to look up the arguments and documentation of each. First, `defadvice`:

```lisp
  (defadvice FUNCTION (CLASS NAME [POSITION] [ARGLIST] FLAG...)
    [DOCSTRING] [INTERACTIVE-FORM]
    BODY...)
```

And then `advice-add`:

```
(advice-add SYMBOL HOW FUNCTION &optional PROPS)
```

It is trivial to rearrange one into the other. Starting with your original:

```lisp
(defadvice expand-abbrev (after my-expand-abbrev activate)
  yadda-yadda-yadda)
```

Rearrange it like this:

```lisp
(defun my-expand-abbrev ()
  "as long as you are making improvements, add a docstring here to document your advice"
  yadda-yadda-yadda)
(advice-add 'expand-abbrev :after #'my-expand-abbrev)
```

Done. Note that I have removed the `activate` flag from the advice; I don’t know why you used it since it seems unnecessary in this case.

Also, see [chapter 13.12.4 Adapting code using the old defadvice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Porting-Old-Advice.html) in the Emacs Lisp manual.

Comment: The `activate` flag is only a `defadvice` thing; without it you need to call `ad-activate` to activate the advice.  It's not relevant to nadvice.

Answer (score 2):

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Advice Combinators` for the different types of advice available.

Most importantly, each description contains a sentence *"More specifically, the composition of the two functions behaves like:"* followed by pseudocode demonstrating the new functionality, which gives you the exact requirements for the function you'll write and how it will be used.  Each pseudocode example is a function receiving -- in the form of `(&rest r)` -- all arguments that the advised function would normally accept, and then some code using those arguments `r` with `OLDFUN` (being the function being advised), and `FUNCTION` (being the advice itself: the function you are writing).

For example, the pseudocode for `:after` is:
`(lambda (&rest r) (prog1 (apply OLDFUN r) (apply FUNCTION r)))`

From this we can see that the new behaviour is:

- Firstly the original function OLDFUN is called with the original argument list.
- Secondly the advice FUNCTION is called with the same argument list.
- Finally the return value of the *original* function is returned.

With nadvice you don't have `ad-return-value` or `ad-arg-N` accessors available, so you need to pick the type of advice which will allow you to access what you need.

For your example this means we can't port `after` defadvice to `:after` nadvice, because (per the pseudocode above) the advice doesn't see the return value of the original function; but `:after-while` is a good match:

```el
(define-advice expand-abbrev (:after-while () my-double-at)
  "Advice to `expand-abbrev'.  Called if there was an expansion.

If the string \"@@\" exists in the expansion then move cursor there
and delete that string.

To disable:
\(advice-remove \\='expand-abbrev \\='expand-abbrev@my-double-at)"
  ;; start idle timer to ensure insertion of abbrev activator
  ;; character (e.g. space) is finished
  (run-with-idle-timer
   0 nil (lambda ()
           (let ((cursor "@@"))
             (if (search-backward cursor last-abbrev-location t)
                 (delete-char (length cursor)))))))
```

(I have not tested that code.)